# Multiple WHERE condition issue at update_batch in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multiple-conditions, batch-updates

Facing problem to used multiple **Where** condition at update_batch in CodeIgniter.

No error message is not showing . **As well as Data is not updating at database.**
But after click **Submit Button** is giving me **flash message** as Data is submitted successfully. But Database could not be able to Update.
Please suggest me what should I do !

**Controller** ------------------------------------

```html
public function masterPrice_update($m_fran_id = null) 
 {
  $sID   = $this->input->post('m_test_id');
  $sAmt  = $this->input->post('m_updated_test_price');
  $sFranId = $this->input->post('m_fran_id');

  for ($i= 0; $i < count($sID); $i++)
  {
   
   $edited_test[] = array(
    'm_test_id' => $sID[$i],
    'm_updated_test_price' => $sAmt[$i],
    'm_fran_id' => $sFranId[$i]
   );
  }

  if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
   $this->franchise_price_model->singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test);

   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', display('save_successfully'));
   redirect('branch/franchise_price/masterPrice_update');
  }
 }
```

**Modal** ---------------------

```html
public function singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test =[], $sFranId ='')
{ 
 $this->db
 ->where('m_fran_id',$sFranId)
 ->update_batch($this->fran_test_pricemaster, $edited_test , 'm_test_id' );
}
```

Comment: @KalroKokka  , sir can you please suggest me

Comment: You don't have to use where condition in a model method. You can check here. : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch

Comment: pls tell what is the id based on which you want to update your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $this->db->last_query() to print query. I think you have issue in where condition from controller you are not passing **$sFranId** to model.

Comment: I mean , **$sFranId** its value is not coming from **Controller** to **Modal** ?   @PankajSharma

Comment: you are not passing value in contoller you are passing only one value you are passing  $this->franchise_price_model->singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test); and in model you are taking 2 values function singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test =[], $sFranId ='')

Comment: Then can you please help me how to write the code at **Controller** ??  @PankajSharma

Comment: please try to replace your controller line to this $this->franchise_price_model->singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test,$sFranId);  and also print last query

Comment: I already done the same things , But not getting the desire value .  When run the code , getting error message like  -- **Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'**

Comment: Thank you | Code is running |

Answer (score 0):

> Use this type of Query

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 WHERE condition AND condition2");
```